# Query post using multiple custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code for showing post from "`meta_key=Date`" and it is working fine!

Now i need to include another "`meta_key=Top`" using numeric meta_value into my query for showing post and ordered by this `meta_value` but i can't figure out the function.

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance,
Shafin

```
<?php 
   $daily_date = get_option('cus_daily_date');
   query_posts("category_name=sports&meta_key=Date&orderby=meta_value&order=asc&meta_value=$daily_date"); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here for details http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters